# How to set a date and time to JSpinner in JAVA (Netbeans)?

Tags: java, string, swing, simpledateformat, jspinner

I have a date and time value in `String` type.

```
String dateTime = "2012-10-27 19:00:00.000";
```

And I have a `JSpinner` named `spnDateTime` with Spinner Model Type as Date.

What I need to do is get the String variable's value and set to the spinner's date and time .

I'm new to JAVA and this is what I tried to do.

```
spnDateTime.setValue(dateTime);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `SimpleDateFrmat` to parse the `String` to a `Date` value

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS").parse(daetTime);
```

Comment: I got this error: 

incompatible types
  required: java.sql.Date
  found:    java.util.Date

Comment: Where? As far as I'm aware, SimpleDateFormat should be returning a java.util.Date

Comment: Ok, I found what's wrong. I have imported java.sql.Date instead of import java.util.Date

Now it works fine. Thanks a lot, life saver.

Comment: I also need to know how to get the value of `String time = "05:54:00.0000000"` as the value of the JSpinner same. (never mind the date in the JSpinner).

Comment: @DishonMichael the process applies. Look up SimpleDateFormat for the required values and there meanings. Your spinner will need a formatter of some kind,Mobutu I'm pretty sure if you do a quick search you'll find some examples, I think I did one